# delete specific columns when other column has specific value (perl or awk)

Tags: perl, if-statement, awk

I have a file with 16 different columns (tab-separated values):

> ```
> 22    51169729    G   39  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   38  0.974359    T   1   0.025641
> 22    51169730    A   36  A   36  1   C   0   0   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169731    C   39  A   0   0   C   39  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169732    G   37  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   37  1   T   0   0
> 22    51169733    G   33  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   33  1   T   0   0
> 22    51169734    C   35  A   0   0   C   35  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169735    A   32  A   32  1   C   0   0   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169736    G   32  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   32  1   T   0   0
> 22    51169737    C   30  A   0   0   C   30  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169738    T   27  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   0   0   T   27  1
> 22    51169739    G   26  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   26  1   T   0   0
> 22    51169740    A   25  A   25  1   C   0   0   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169741    C   22  A   0   0   C   22  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169742    G   23  A   0   0   C   0   0   G   23  1   T   0   0
> 22    51169743    C   21  A   0   0   C   21  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169744    C   22  A   0   0   C   22  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169745    C   19  A   0   0   C   19  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169746    C   19  A   0   0   C   19  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169747    A   15  A   14  0.933333    C   1   0.0666667   G   0   0   T   0   0
> 22    51169748    C   20  A   0   0   C   20  1   G   0   0   T   0   0
> ```

The third column can be A, G, C or T.

I would like to:

- remove columns 5, 6 and 7 when column 3 is an 'A' OR when $7=='0'.
- Similarly, remove columns 8, 9, 10 when $3== 'C' OR when $10=='0'.
- remove columns 11, 12, 13 when $3=='G' OR when $13=='0'.
- and remove columns 14, 15, 16 when $3=='T' OR when $16=='0'.

When this is done for the entire file, there would only be 4 columns left in some cases and 7 columns in other cases, like in the following example:

> ```
> 22    51169729    G   39  T   1   0.025641
> 22    51169730    A   36  
> 22    51169731    C   39  
> 22    51169732    G   37  
> 22    51169733    G   33  
> 22    51169734    C   35  
> 22    51169735    A   32  
> 22    51169736    G   32  
> 22    51169737    C   30  
> 22    51169738    T   27  
> 22    51169739    G   26  
> 22    51169740    A   25  
> 22    51169741    C   22  
> 22    51169742    G   23  
> 22    51169743    C   21  
> 22    51169744    C   22  
> 22    51169745    C   19  
> 22    51169746    C   19  
> 22    51169747    A   15  C   2   0.133333    
> 22    51169748    C   20
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `In a second part if more than one column in columns 7, 10 and 13 has a value of zero, I would like to remove one of these values.` looks a bit contradictory with the example `For example: column 7 and column 10 contain a 0, than I would like to remove columns 8, 9 and 10. I don't even know if this possible. `

Comment: Can you show an example input file containing all the scenarios?

Comment: In the 2nd part when you talk about columns/fields 7, 10, and 13 - is that the original field numbers or the field numbers after the first part has removed some fields? wrt `I would like to remove one of these values` - how do you decide which one? Why are you removing fields 8,9, and 10? You really need to post a FEW lines of representative input and expected output that covers all of your cases, not just 1 line covering 1 part of 1 case.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution for the first part:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %remove = ( A => 4,                # Where to start removing the columns
               C => 7,                # for a given character in column #3.
               G => 10,
               T => 13,
             );

$\ = "\n";                            # Add newline to prints.
$, = "\t";                            # Separate values by tabs.

while (<>) {                          # Read input line by line;
    chomp;                            # Remove newline.
    my @F = split /\t/;               # Split on tabs, populate an array.
    splice @F, $remove{ $F[2] }, 3;   # Remove the columns.
    print @F;                         # Output.
}
```

Once you clarify the second requirement, I can try to add more code. What values do you want to remove? Can you show more examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do the first part, assuming no empty fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$3 == "A" { $5=$6=$7="" }
$3 == "C" { $8=$9=$10="" }
$3 == "G" { $11=$12=$13="" }
$3 == "T" { $14=$15=$16="" }
{ gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"\t"); print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       957584  C       157     A       1       0.006   G       0       0       T       0       0
```

I don't really understand what you're trying to do in the 2nd part but it sounds like this might be what you want if the test on $7/10/13 is the modified field numbers after the first phase:

```
$3 == "A" { $5=$6=$7="" }
$3 == "C" { $8=$9=$10="" }
$3 == "G" { $11=$12=$13="" }
$3 == "T" { $14=$15=$16="" }
{ $0=$0 }
$7  ~ /0/ { c++ }
$10 ~ /0/ { c++ }
$13 ~ /0/ { c++ }
c > 1 { $8=$9=$10="" }
{ c=0; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"\t"); print }
```

or this if the test on $7/10/13 is the original field numbers:

```
$7  ~ /0/ { c++ }
$10 ~ /0/ { c++ }
$13 ~ /0/ { c++ }
$3 == "A" { $5=$6=$7="" }
$3 == "C" { $8=$9=$10="" }
$3 == "G" { $11=$12=$13="" }
$3 == "T" { $14=$15=$16="" }
c > 1 { $8=$9=$10="" }
{ c=0; gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"\t"); print }
```

If not, edit your question to clarify with a better example.

Comment: The 'gsub' doesn't work for me. Is there another way to work around it?

Comment: That depends - in what does it "not work"? Does it not change the string, change it to the wrong thing, core dump, syntax error, or something else? What is the string before/after the gsub()? Is it the first or second solution above you are using? How do you know it's the gsub() that's not doing what you want vs some other part of the script? What version of awk are you using? On what OS?

Comment: I cannot install the String::Gsub because CPAN doesn't find a mirror site. I made a perl script, using Ubuntu OS and the first solution. Can you do it in command line?

open "chr22", "chr22.bamrc" or die $!;
open "chr22test", ">", "chr22.test.bamrc" or die $!;
while (<chr22>)
{
 if ('$3' eq "A") { $5=$6=$7="";};
 if ('$3' eq "C") { $8=$9=$10="";};
 if ('$3' eq "G") { $11=$12=$13="";};
 if ('$3' eq "T") { $14=$15=$16="";};
 if ('$7' eq "0") { $5=$6=$7="";};
 if ('$10' eq "0") { $8=$9=$10="";};
 if ('$13' eq "0") { $11=$12=$13="";};
 { gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"\t");};
  print chr22test $_;
}

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? What I posted is awk, not perl.